# How to put the control element above the map so that they will fill the entire height of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm putting the control element above the div with my map and vertical scrollbar appears. Can anybody tell me how to put the elements one above the other, so that they will fill the entire height of the screen without vertical scrollbar?

```
<style type="text/css">

html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
}

#mySelector {
    margin-top:10px;
    width:400px;
}

#map {
    margin-top:10px;
}

</style>
```

```
<select id="mySelector"></select>
<div id="map"></div>
```

The code:
http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/n3LshvLL

Comment: Could you provide more detail as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/n3LshvLL/ There is a vertical scrollbar that I don't need. My purpose is to fill the page on 100% of height with the control element and my map without the scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n3LshvLL/5/

I have added `overflow:hidden` and given `height:90%` to map. Please not that, the moment you increase `height` more than 90% than it will create problem, as you are telling map to cover entire area.

Comment: In this case the control hides behind the top of the screen when I drag the map and there is no way to return it without the scrollbar